# Not having `.html` in Website URL?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, web

How is it possible to have a url of a basic website, **not** include the `.html` at the end of a webpage?

My website is just a few pages, but I don't like having the `.html` in my link: `www.mywebsite.com/mypage.html`

If I type: `www.mywebsite.com/mypage`, of course, it's not found :(

I navigate around my site just using typical hyperlinks.
Probably a dumb question, but I've googled it and the stuff I find is way more complex than just html code and is usually referring to php or perl.

Thanks.

Comment: It's handled any number of ways. Some servers have url rewriting rules for redirecting resources. Some technologies like asp.net have routing rules that the server uses to parse various actions and resources. Look up url rewriting and mvc (they are separate concepts).

Comment: Google "mod_rewrite"

Answer (score 0):

You sinply make an .htaccess file and put the following in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

What web server software are you using?  If Apache, you will likely be interested in the `rewrite` mod.

Something like the following:

`RewriteRule ^mypage/?$ mypage.html [NC,L]`

In your .htaccess file.  I believe you need to enable the mod first too.

Answer (score -3):

Simple solution is to change the name of your website from mypage.html to mypage